# dkimproxy unable to read private key

Tags: permissions, opensuse, chmod, dkim

I just found this error in my server logs

```
May 17 14:55:07 marcus dkimproxy.out[1005]: signing error: Error: cannot read /etc/ssl/private/dkim_server/dkim_server.key: Permission denied
```

dkimproxy runs as `dkim` user, member of both `dkim` and `ssl-private` groups. The key file is chmodded as follows

```
# l /etc/ssl/private/dkim_server/

drwxr-x---  2 dkim ssl-private 4096 12 dic  2009 ./
drwxr-x--- 10 root ssl-private 4096 11 apr 16.37 ../
-rw-r-----  1 dkim ssl-private  891 12 dic  2009 dkim_server.key
-rw-r-----  1 dkim ssl-private  272 12 dic  2009 dkim_server.pub
```

I also did as root `sudo -u dkim cat /etc/ssl/private/dkim_server/dkim_server.key` and it works.

I had the same problem yesterday but I simply forgot to add dkim to ssl-private group. After I fixed that I thought I was done

Now seems that dkimproxy is still unable to read the private key.

What could I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It now works.

Edited `/etc/init.d/dkimproxy`

Changed

```
DKIMPROXYGROUP=ssl-private
```

and restarted...

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu, make the change in the /etc/default/dkimproxy file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that dkim user unable to access /etc/ssl/private directory, and possibly /etc/ssl
Either add dkim user to ssl-private group or do `chmod o+rx /etc/ssl /etc/ssl/private`. However second choice is somewhat insecure.

Comment: dkim is already in the ssl-private group. Yesterday it wasn't because of my error, but now it is

Comment: Also I did some sudo -u dkim ls /etc... /etc/ssl... /etc/ssl/private etc. All directory listings appeared

Comment: did you restart it after modifying user?

Comment: I just restarted and made a new test (I already restarted several times during the past hours) but I found the guilty message a few lines above the tail of my logs

Comment: Another weird thing. I enabled /bin/bash as shell for dkim, then did "su dkim" to get full shell access. I could navigate to all directories I needed and even cat the private key file. AFAIK dkimproxy doesn't run in chroot, and, still AFAIK, if you run chrooted you either get a file not found error or read the file you want, you never get a permission denied error